# Siddhi CEP: Multiple results per group when using time window

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, siddhi

Using siddhi 3.0.3 as Java library

I am seeing some unexpected behavior when using group by with a time window. The general issue is that I get the correct result aggregations for the group, but I receive one aggregated result per event, not one per group.

Specifically,

Using the following query, with no time window:

```
@info(name = 'RealTimeQuery') from MyEventStream
select EventName as EventName, count() as Count, avg(ElapsedTime) as Avg_ElapsedTime
group by EventName output snapshot every 30 seconds insert into CEP_Result;
```

I get one result per unique EventName, with the proper counts and avg. So, in my example, there are 15 unique EventNames, and each unique EventName occurs 10 times for a total of 150 events. I get 15 results, one for each EventName, with each having a count of 10 and the correct average, as I would expect.

However, if I add a time window to this query:

```
@info(name = 'RealTimeQuery') from MyEventStream#window.time(2 minutes)
select EventName as EventName, count() as Count, avg(ElapsedTime) as Avg_ElapsedTime
group by EventName output snapshot every 30 seconds insert into CEP_Result;
```

The result for each EventName is correct, as it has the correct count and average. But, instead of one result per EventName, I get 10, for a total of 150 results.

We're looking to replace Esper with Siddhi, so I ran similar queries through Esper, and with Esper, in both cases, I received the expected output of one result per EventName.

Answer (score 2):

This can be sorted by using a time batch window [1] instead of a time window. Time window is a sliding window where as it will calculate window time backward from the event received time and trigger. In the batch window it will calculate the window from the first event arrival and send all the events once its expired. You can use Siddhi Try it [2] tool of WSO2 CEP product and simulate events with Siddhi queries.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Inbuilt+Windows#InbuiltWindows-timeBatchtimeBatch

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Siddhi+Try+It+Tool